# Запуск асинхронных функций

Tags: python, асинхронность

Скажите, пожалуйста, каким правильно использовать запуска функций в асинхронном варианте?
Есть список с вложенными списками. Где каждый список представляет из себя будущие значения для функции.

```
c = [[121, 'yes', 5],[345, 'no', 1]]

sphere = 121
dart = 'yes'
number = 5
```

Есть функция:

```
def test(sphere, dart, nubmer)
```

Я бы хотел совершить следующие действия

```
for element in c:
    sphere, dart, number = c[0], c[1], c[2]
    #дальше мне надо запускать функцию в асинхронном режиме.
    #Как мне сделать так, чтобы она сама завершалась? Это нужно прописывать в самой функции?
    #Или же надо останавливать поток непосредственно после каждого элемента итерации?
```

Comment: Показанная функция не является асинхронной, поэтому что значит "запуск асинхронных функций" и "в асинхронном режиме" - непонятно

Comment: Я неправильно сказал. Вы правы. Каждая функция запущенная с параметрами из списка должна исполняться отдельным поток до самозавершения. Так понятно?

Comment: Ну значит просто взять и запустить этот самый отдельный поток `threading.Thread(target=test, args=element).start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, данное решение подойдёт для Вас:

```
import asyncio

async def test(sphere, dart, number): # Поменять def на async def.
    # Do Something.
    return

async def task_starter(input_array):
    for element in input_array:
        asyncio.create_task(test(element[0], element[1], element[2]))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.gather(coro_starter(c))
loop.run_forever()
```

В таком случае будет ожидаться завершение работы Вашей функции.

Comment: Дак мне необходимо, что функция в итерации запускалась и итерация с запусками продолжилась. В самой функции будет таймер, который ее завершит. Вижу это так.

Comment: Исправил, если на этот раз понял как Вы поставили задачу.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду разбирать и знакомиться. Выглядит не очень сложно.

Comment: @6 crimes , а если `async def test(sphere, dart, number)` содержит другие функции? Они же не должны быть асинхронными?

Comment: @Antony , что вы имеете ввиду? Если вы хотите вызвать из функции test другую функцию, то нет, не должны быть.